# Style the QTreeView/QTreeWidget item in edit state

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qtstylesheets, qitemdelegate

I want to style using `QSS` the line edit that appears when I edit a `QTreeView/QTreeWidget` item.

Here is an example:

[image]

This is a standard `QTreeWidget` with `QTreeView::item { min-height: 25px; }` style applied to it.

My question is: Is it possible to have the line edit that appears when I double click the item the same size as the item itself? Or maybe of a certain height in pixels?

*Note:* I wouldn't want to use a custom delegate for this, I would like to do it in `QSS` only.